# Tensorflow "undefined symbol" when loading custom GPU op

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am using Tensorflow 1.9rc0 compiled from sources using bazel version 0.15.0. I'm using cuda support with cuda version 9.2 and cudnn version 7.

I am trying to build a custom op which executes a cuda kernel. I've followed the [doumentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) regarding that matter and checked a few implemented ops in order to develop it.

I ended up with the following code:

*kernel_example.h:*

```
#ifndef KERNEL_EXAMPLE_H_
#define KERNEL_EXAMPLE_H_

#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h"

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/register_types.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/types.h"


namespace functor {

template <typename Device,typename T>
struct ExampleFunctor {
  void operator()(const Device& d,
                  const T* input, const T* filter, T* output,
                  int in_depth, int input_cols, int input_rows,
                  int out_depth, int filter_cols, int filter_rows,
                  int stride_rows, int stride_cols,
                  int n_elements);
};

#if GOOGLE_CUDA

typedef Eigen::GpuDevice GPUDevice;

template <typename T>
struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, T> {
    void operator()(
        const GPUDevice& d,
        const T* input, const T* filter, T* output,
        int in_depth, int input_cols, int input_rows,
        int out_depth, int filter_cols, int filter_rows,
        int stride_rows, int stride_cols,
        int n_elements);
};

#endif //GOOGLE_CUDA

}
```

*kernel_example.cc:*

```
#include "kernel_example.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/common_shape_fns.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

using CPUDevice = Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice;
using GPUDevice = Eigen::GpuDevice;

REGISTER_OP("MyConvGpu")
    .Input("input: T")
    .Input("filter: T")
    .Output("output: T")
    .SetShapeFn(tensorflow::shape_inference::UnknownShape);

// OpKernel definition.
// template parameter <T> is the datatype of the tensors.
template <typename Device, typename T>
class ExampleOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ExampleOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Loading op parameters and defining  variables

    functor::ExampleFunctor<Device, T> functor;
    functor(
        context->eigen_device<Device>(),
        input.flat<T>().data(),
        filter.flat<T>().data(),
        output->flat<T>().data(),
        in_depth, input_cols, input_rows,
        out_depth, filter_cols, filter_rows,
        stride_rows, stride_cols,
        static_cast<int>(output->NumElements()));
  }
};

#if GOOGLE_CUDA

#define REGISTER_GPU_KERNEL(T)                                    \
  REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("Example")                         \
                              .Device(DEVICE_GPU)                 \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T"),            \
                              ExampleOp<GPUDevice, T>);

TF_CALL_GPU_NUMBER_TYPES(REGISTER_GPU_KERNEL);

//REGISTER_GPU_KERNEL(Eigen::half)
REGISTER_GPU_KERNEL(float)
REGISTER_GPU_KERNEL(double)
REGISTER_GPU_KERNEL(int)

#endif
```

*kernel_example.cu.cc:*

```
#ifdef GOOGLE_CUDA

#define EIGEN_USE_GPU
#include "kernel_example.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/cuda_kernel_helper.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

namespace functor {

// Define the CUDA kernel.
template <typename T>
__global__ void ExampleCudaKernel(const T* input, const T* filter, T* output,
                               const int batch_size,
                               const int in_depth, const int input_cols, const int input_rows,
                               const int out_depth, const int filter_cols, const int filter_rows,
                               const int stride_rows, const int stride_cols,
                               const int n_elements) {
    // Kernel here
}

// Define the GPU implementation that launches the CUDA kernel.
template <typename T>
void ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, T>::operator()(
    const Eigen::GpuDevice& d,
    const T* input, const T* filter, T* output,
    int in_depth, int input_cols, int input_rows,
    int out_depth, int filter_cols, int filter_rows,
    int stride_rows, int stride_cols,
    int n_elements) {

  // Launch the cuda kernel.
  ExampleCudaKernel<T>
        <<<(n_elements + 255) / 256, 256>>>(input, filter, output,
                                             batch_size,
                                             in_depth, input_cols, input_rows,
                                             out_depth, filter_cols, filter_rows,
                                             stride_rows, stride_cols,
                                             n_elements);
}

// Explicitly instantiate functors for the types of OpKernels registered.
template struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, float>;
template struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, double>;
template struct ExampleFunctor<GPUDevice, int>;

} //namespace functor

#endif  // GOOGLE_CUDA
```

Everything compiles correctly, generating a *example.so* library file, with the following bazel build file:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "example.so",
    srcs = ["kernel_example.h", "kernel_example.cc"],
    gpu_srcs = ["kernel_example.h", "kernel_example.cu.cc"],
)
```

However, when loading this library into a Tensorflow execution using

```
module = tf.load_op_library('./example.so')
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist.py", line 51, in <module>
    my_conv_gpu_module = tf.load_op_library('./example.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ./example.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow16FormatFromStringERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPNS_12TensorFormatE
```

I've developed other ops, which don't use cuda acceleration, and there is no problem loading them, even though their implementation is pretty similar.

Also, I've read other topics regarding this error but the solution always seems to be adding this **--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"** flag to bazel build arguments, given that Tensoflow's  binary pip packages are built using gcc version 4. I'm doing so, but the error persists.

I've also tried this code on a different environment, with Tensorflow rc1.8, cuda 8 and cudnn 6. But without any luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: That's very likely to be an ABI issue. I had the error message. Bazel seems to *not* propagate the flags correctly. At some point I gave up and just used gcc4 as the default. Then switched to I building TF from source with ABI=1 and gcc7 and do not use bazel for custom ops anymore.

Comment: I've just tried gcc4 as default but it doesn't seem to help. 
I've also tried building the op manually, using the documented commands, but I get errors when importing other tensorflow stuff as it seems to not be aware of the file hierarchy. How do you do it?

Comment: I testing my stuff on TF1.8, TF1.9rc0, TF1.9rc1 based on my [boiler-plate code](https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op) using CMake ;-)

Comment: I tried your boiler-plate code and the same error arises. Tested it with different gcc versions. The matrix_add op you provide as default compiles correctly, and I am able to load it (which I don't understand why, given mine does not and uses the same scheme), however it fails the provided tests when I use the GPU. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Fails by `undefined symbol`?  Did you try to build TensorFlow with ABI=1 from source. I have a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/PatWie/aef90e72dbeaf2f79fbcaa031d74baad) which I execute to regularly update TensorFlow. (DO not forget to use either r1.8 or 1.9, master is constantly broken).

Comment: Did you find any solution in the end? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: If I remember correctly it had to do with using different gcc versions to build Tensorflow and to build the custom op.

Answer (score 0):

`cxxopt` only applies to C++ compilation. Try using both `copt` and `cxxopt` and set them to `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`